# problem with openNI and openNI2 not locating ASUS Xtion

Tags: kinect, openni2, xtion, jackal, asus

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I would like to ask for help on using my ASUS Xtion camera on my Clearpath Jackal with openni or openni2. When i turn on the jackal and try to view raw image data, I can view an image very well. The problem is that when I try to open openni and openni2, the following error appears:

```
[ INFO] [1464705771.982015207]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.6/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 631 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
```

It seems like it is trying to find a device (my camera), and never finds it. I also ran lsusb to see if my camera showed up, and what I got was this:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 192f:0916 Avago Technologies, Pte. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I see no ASUS written as one of the bus drives (as suggested in http://answers.ros.org/question/191630/problem-with-openni2_camera-primesense-not-detected/)

I have followed this procedure that was also suggested to me : http://robotica.unileon.es/mediawiki/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_troubleshooting#No_device_found_.2F_No_devices_connected, but it also did not work.

Let me know if anyone has any tips on how to fix this with my ASUS Xtion. Thanks :)

EDIT 1: I did `lsusb` while i was ssh'ed into my jackal and my ASUS actually showed up on the list, so I am starting to think that I have to run the openni from my robot's computer, is that true?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235690/problem-with-openni-and-openni2-not-locating-asus-xtion-(no-matching-device-found....-waiting-for-devices,-invalid-device-number-1,-there-are-0-devices-connected.)/) by [Gabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27033/gabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2016-06-01**:
If the system is not detecting it, it doesn't look good. Have you tried it in another computer? You should also check `dmesg` to see if there was some problem when detecting the device.

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2016-06-06**:
Openni will launch the device driver, which will try to connect to a physical address in the computer it is running. So yes, you should definitely launch openni in the same computer that has the camera plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you happen to be using a USB 3.0 port?  I know that XTION devices have to undergo a firmware upgrade in order to work on a USB 3.0 port.  (even the USB 2.0 devices)

Some more information about this is at https://github.com/nh2/asus-xtion-fix

---

Originally posted by [superjax](https://answers.ros.org/users/20144/superjax/) with karma: 51 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0